# How to edit your views in CouchDB Futon?

Tags: couchdb

I am using CouchDB Futon to edit the views and shows. But I find it hard to edit the JavaScript code because of converting the newline to "\n". Also, it is hard to do all the escaping work.

What do you use to edit your views?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you want to have a look at the CouchApp framework. It allows you to have your map, reduce, show, list etc. functions in text files you can edit with the editor of your choice. A simple command pushes them to your design documents. It is intended for building CouchApps, but might as well be useful if you only need to edit your views.

- http://couchapp.org
- http://github.com/couchapp/couchapp

Answer (score 2):

You can edit view code by browsing to it in Futon, and then expanding the source code area. You can then save/undo, etc.

For the other functions, and views too, you can always use [LoveSeat](http://www.russiantequila.com/wordpress/?p=119).

Cheers.

Comment: It's built with .NET so it works best on Windows, but it's built to work with Mono, a cross platform .NET library. Just install it (http://www.mono-project.com/) and then LoveSeat, and you're set! I've succeeded on Ubuntu and heard success stories of OSX. Cheers.

Comment: Using the source code area doesn't help with the newline-problem. Couchdb expects \n instead of newline. At this point i find futon impossible to use for view-development.